# Err:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release 404 Not Found [IP: 18.67.240.19 443]

Tags: linux, docker

My `lsb_release -a` output is as below

```
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I am trying to download Docker from [official webpage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/) but all the time I am having below error.

```
>sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary jammy InRelease
Hit:3 http://apt.pop-os.org/release jammy InRelease
Err:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.67.240.19 443]
Hit:5 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:6 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://apt.pop-os.org/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` file has nothing in it. `sources.list` file as shown as below:

```
## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 22.04 _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20221026)]/ jammy main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 22.04 _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20221026)]/ stable main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 22.04 _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20221026)]/ unstable main restricted
```

Also, I have tried to add `[truested=yes] (https://download.docker.com/linux/debian)` and that also didn't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jammy is a Ubuntu codename, so you can't pull that from the Debian directory.

Look in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for the docker config, and change the Debian reference to Ubuntu. That will get you to the correct [download directory](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I got the same error when I try to install something (not only docker) in a new linux distro.

What has worked for me is

- If the error is in the x version of distro but it worked in x-1 version, I replace the new `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` with the old
- If the error is in my new cool distro, I use the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` of another linux distro (friend, coworker, etc) in which the required tool was installed without errors.
- Sometimes it was networks issues (mine or linux public repositories). So after some hours, the same command worked

### Steps

- Take a backup of

  - `/etc/apt/sources.list`
  - `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`
- Use my sources.list (ubuntu 22)

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

**/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list**

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu       bionic stable
```

- Execute `sudo apt-get update`

If it don't work, restore both files with your backup